# Regex Positive and Negative Lookahead

Tags: python

I need help with a regex.
Indeed, I try to find the words:

*"RESULTATS", "NOMS", "ECHANTILLONS"*

But if there are "les" in front of result I don't want my regex to match.
I work with Python. So I opted for a regex of type:

```
REGEX_NOMS_COL = re.compile("^(?!(les))R.SULTAT.*|NOMS|ECHANTILLON.*|analyses", re.IGNORECASE)
```

the various points in my regex are there pr filled with possible accents.
My regex works in part ... It works fine on the regex101 ^^ site but less in my code, where "the results" are taken into account when it shouldn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are matching the negative look ahead incorrectly. Try putting it after the words. This is inline with the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> **`(?!...)`**
>
> For example, `Isaac (?!Asimov)` will match `'Isaac '` only if it’s not followed by `'Asimov'`.

```
(?:RESULTATS|NOMS|ECHANTILLONS)(?!les)
```

- As in the documentation, this will match any of `'RESULTATS'`, `'NOMS'`, or `'ECHANTILLONS'` only if it's not followed by `'les'`

[image]